# Installation of Win 7 using Virtual Box on Ubuntu 12.04 shows error

Tags: installation, windows, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 system with x86-64 bit system architecture. Every time I try to install any windows OS using virtual box it shows error "FATAL ERROR: boot medium halted or not found". What do I do next? What is causing this problem? Tried several online links for installing windows OS on Ubuntu using Virtual Box and also for installing virtual box.
The virtual box is installed correctly as per my thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the hard drive image still attacked to the virtual machine? If not, attach it as a SATA controller.

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between different virtual disks that it asks to create?

Comment: Got it! have to setup virtual hard disk as .vmdk and not as .vdi. Thanks man. you set the screws rolling.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Ubuntu. This is an error within Virtual Box.

The meaning of the error message is that your virtual machine can't find any bootable media.

Make sure you specify in you virtual machine that it should search your physical dvd drive for the install dvd, or point it to the iso file containing your Windows7 install and it should work.

Comment: Yes I do select the .iso file directly for the boot.. still it is showing the same error...

Comment: Sounds like the ISO is broken then. You can verify burning it to a real dvd and attempting to boot. of.Or the easiest way wold be to to just make another iso.

Comment: as mentioned above the problem was in selecting the type of hard disk to be created by virtual box, was initially selecting .vdi whereas I needed to setup in ".vmdk". Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, as mentioned above. So please check which virtual hard disk you create before you actually create one. Problem was to setup in .vmdk and not in .vdi.
There lies the answer to this problem. Thanks to those who gave thoughts to this.